# Reading 39 digit number from excel sheet using c#

Tags: c#, excel-2007

Excel cannot process data more than 64 bit (Big it will store it in powers of 10), but in our application I want 128bit data, for that I have formatted particular cell to be text format in excel sheet, so that I can enter very big number. Now I am able to enter big number, but not able to read that particular cell in code and also gives error for that cell. 
I am using OleDbConnection in C#.

Comment: why do you need such large numbers? Are you doing cosmology?

Comment: if it's a card ID, it's a string rather than a number, right?

Comment: Forget about whether card ID or something else, I want read that cell as string itself. If the number is less than 14 digits it is able to read, once I enter big number due to which error would come for that particular cell than onwards it is not able to read.

Comment: "There are 10^11 stars in the galaxy. That used to be a huge number. But it's only a hundred billion. It's less than the national deficit! We used to call them astronomical numbers. Now we should call them economical numbers."  --Feynman

Comment: Please show the code you are using now and the error you get.

Answer (score 3):

You mention that it is some sort of card ID, which to me says it's a string rather than a true number.

But, if you really have to manipulate as an integer, have you looked at [BigInteger](http://www.codeplex.com/biginteger)?

[BigInteger, GetFiles, and More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163696.aspx)

Update in response to comments: @Shashikiran: you seem to be treating the symptoms rather than the cause. Your real problem appears to be reading a string longer than 14 chars, when excel is treating the cell contents as a number rather than string (due to all numeric chars). Sounds like you need to tell Excel it's a string rather than a number, I believe you do this by pre-fixing with 'A'

Answer (score 0):

Can you read that cell as a string and then convert it to a biginteger?

C# has no built-in 128-bit integer data type.

Comment: It doesn't have a BigInteger type yet either (though it should be in .NET 4), unless you count the J# libary.

Comment: I am reading it as string, but even number is present in that cell, it is no able read (means empty). I am able to read other cells. If the number is less than 14 digits it is able to read, once I enter big number due to which error would come for that particular cell than onwards it is not able to read.